# Oriented Rubiks Cube 4x4 re-arrange center pieces

Tags: algorithms, rubiks-cube

There are a lot solutions for oriented 3x3. They rotate all center pieces. I'm trying to solve oriented 4x4 with `GabbasSoft Cube Demo`. Luckily blue and green centers were same orientation, so I just rotated them correctly with 3x3 algorithm. But other centers are shuffled:

[image]

[image]

Is there some algorithms to re-arrange center pieces without break edges and corners?

Comment: You might want to also try [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you! Created copy there.

Comment: You are welcome :)